# Change chart series colours when enabled, depending on series[index]

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Just a quick one.
I have a graph that has the possibility to display 9 different series, data comes in through textboxes from user and populates these respective series.

The graph is linked to a checkedlistbox and the items that are checked in the listbox enable their respective series on the chart. Only 2 series may be enabled at any one time, which works without a problem using the code below:

```
    private void chListBoxChartSeries_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Count >= 2)
        {
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }
    }

    public void saveChartSeries()
    {
        //placeholder variable to relate between checklist item and chart series
        string seriesName;

        for (int index = 0; index < chListBoxChartSeries.Items.Count; ++index)
        {
            seriesName = chListBoxChartSeries.Items[index].ToString();
            if (chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Contains(chListBoxChartSeries.Items[index]))
            {
                main.chartVitals.Series[seriesName].Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                main.chartVitals.Series[seriesName].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

There's one thing I do want to do following this, I would like whichever series are enabled to be set to a colour each (first series red, second series blue for example). I'm struggling to find an efficient way to do this, but I imagine it involves setting the first of the two indexes to one colour (red) and the second to another colour (blue). I figure I can do this using the existing for-loop in the saveChartSeries() function, something like this:

```
    public void saveChartSeries()
    {
        //placeholder variable to relate between checklist item and chart series
        string seriesName;

        for (int index = 0; index < chListBoxChartSeries.Items.Count; ++index)
        {
            seriesName = chListBoxChartSeries.Items[index].ToString();
            if (chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Contains(chListBoxChartSeries.Items[index]))
            {
                main.chartVitals.Series[seriesName].Enabled = true;
                if (main.chartVitals.Series[seriesName].Enabled == true)
                {
                    //set series color to Color.Red
                    //if there is already a red series, set to Color.Blue
                }
            }
            else
            {
                main.chartVitals.Series[seriesName].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is about as much as I can get so far, if anyone can offer a next step, or if I'm over-complicating it and there's a simpler way, I'd really appreciate someone pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to color each visible series with a color from a fixed list.

That will involve changing subsequent series' colors whenever you enable or disable a previous series, right?

Here is a function that will do that:

```
void colorSeries(Chart chart)
{
    List<Color> seriescolors = new List<Color> 
       { Color.Khaki, Color.Brown, Color.CornflowerBlue,
         Color.DarkCyan, Color.ForestGreen, Color.Gold, Color.HotPink, Color.Indigo};

    int co = 0;
    foreach (Series s in chart.Series)
        if (s.Enabled) s.Color = seriescolors[co++];
}
```

You would call it each time you enable or disable a Series.

You also wrote: *if I'm over-complicating it* and *I figure I can do this using the existing for-loop*. Hmm. In my opion you are both overcomplicating it and also setting a completely wrong priority.

Do not try to fit something in an 'existing loop'; instead keep things simple and call a function to take care of the display colors after you have processed the user actions.

Try to  **'separate concerns'**, and always aim at creating **small and self-sufficient** routines!

Comment: That has it working, so thankyou for that. Also thankyou for your advice, I'll take that on board in the future and will attempt to optimise my code for this program using those principles.